# Interchange symmetry of a tensor of type $(0,4)$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Suppose $A$ is a tensor of type  $(0,4)$ on any manifold having the following symmetries
$$A_{abcd}=-A_{bacd}=-A_{abdc}$$
and 
$$A_{abdc}+A_{acbd}+A_{adcb}=0.$$

How can I show that

$$A_{abcd}=A_{cdab}?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is much easier to use (and remember) the second symmetry if you write it as

$$A_{abcd} + A_{acdb} + A_{adbc} = 0.$$

That is, you fix the first index and cyclically permute the remaining three.

As for the desired symmetry,

\begin{align*}
A_{abcd} &= -A_{acdb} - A_{adbc}\\
&= A_{cadb} + A_{dabc}\\
&= -A_{cdba} - A_{cbad} - A_{dbca} - A_{dcab}\\
&= A_{cdab} + A_{bcad} + A_{bdca} + A_{cdab}\\
&= 2A_{cdab} - A_{badc}\\
&= 2A_{cdab} + A_{abdc}\\
&= 2A_{cdab} - A_{abcd}.
\end{align*}

Adding $A_{abcd}$ to both sides and dividing by two, we see that $A_{abcd} = A_{cdab}$.

If $A$ is a tensor field on the manifold $M$, then this calculation shows that $A \in S^2\left(\bigwedge^2 T^*M\right)$.

---

One tensor with these symmetries is the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor). For this tensor, the second symmetry is known as the first Bianchi identity.